# Image uploading to storage laravel 5.2 not working using intervention (not using input)

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5

I don't know what am doing wrong, this line of code is not working

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'         => 'required|max:255',
            'slug'          => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id'   => 'required|integer',
            'body'          => 'required'
        ));
    // store in the database
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->slug = $request->slug;
    $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
      $image = $request->file('featured_image');
      $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
      Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('800', '400')->save($location);
      $post->image = $filename;
    }
    $post->save();
    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
    Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

My posts are saving but I can't find image in the images folder or database and its not gives any error.

Comment: did you check that your code inside the if statement gets executed?

Comment: Although the code is working finre now but yeah i did check and it gave me no errors i think it probably using the "Save" instead of "save" i don't what it was i did but i came back the next day and it worked , could it be system ? i honestly don't know .thanks @shock_gone_wild